# Wrap Sentences in Tabular Environment

Tags: latex, tabular

I'm using the tabular environment in Latex (Overleaf) and would like my text to wrap automatically and be justified. The closest I can get to this is to use the `\\` syntax. This is laborious; further, I would like to have justified text, like the rest of my document. I am using a snippet that I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303668/alignment-of-the-sentences), but it does not incorporate automatic wrapping and justified text. My minimum working example follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
%\bibliographystyle{aea}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{newbib3.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Analysis of Editing}\\
    \noindent{Substantive}: 0, -2.\\
    Further: the, mighty.\\
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\ }l}
    Value Added: & Yes, I want the benefit of using the tabular environment.\\ 
    & No, because I would like this text to wrap automatically (instead of extending out continuously) and to be justified. 
    \end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:

Analysis of Editing

Substantive:  0, -2.

Further:  the, mighty.

Value Added: Yes, I want the benefit of using the tabular environment.

No, because I would like this text to wrap automatically (instead of extending out continuously) and to be justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a column of fixed width, e.g. `p{5cm}` or a `tabularx` that will automatically adjust the width of the `X` columns to fill the desired with.

Unrelated note: please do not abuse `\\` for line breaks outside of tables

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
%\bibliographystyle{aea}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{newbib3.bib}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Analysis of Editing}

    \noindent{Substantive}: 0, -2.
    
    Further: the, mighty.
    
    \begin{tabularx}{.953\linewidth}{@{}l@{\ }X}
    Value Added: & Yes, I want the benefit of using the tabular environment.\\ 
    & No, because I would like this text to wrap automatically (instead of extending out continuously) and to be justified. 
    \end{tabularx}   
\end{document}
```

[image]